# Problem of understanding, Why these 2 programs take 3 and 6 seconds respectively

Tags: c

I start programming in C and I cannot understand why these two programs take 3 and 6 seconds respectively to run.
If anyone can help me thanks :)

Program 1 :

```
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            sleep(i);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }    
    return 0;   
}
```

Program 2 :

```
int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        if(fork()==0)
        {
            sleep(i);
            exit(0);
        }
        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not meeting your expectation?

Comment: How long do you think they should take?

Comment: Hi, in my opinion the first and second program should do sleep (1) + sleep (2) + sleep (3) and therefore take 6 seconds each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 and 6 seconds are the correct amount of time each should run.

The difference between the two is that one spawns all three processes and then waits on all of them simultaneously, while the other spawns one process and then waits before spawning the other. This is the effect of moving the `wait(NULL)` inside or outside the loop.

```
Program 1:
t    parent      child 1     child 2     child 3
0    fork()x3    sleep       sleep       sleep
1    wait                    sleep       sleep
2    wait                                sleep
3    done

Program 2
t    parent      child 1     child 2     child 3
0    fork();wait sleep       
1    fork();wait             sleep
2    wait                    sleep
3    fork();wait                         sleep
4    wait                                sleep
5    wait                                sleep
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first program, the loop that calls `fork()` doesn't wait for wach child to exit before it continues and creates the next child. So all 3 children are started at about the same time.

The second loop then waits for all of them to exit. It will complete when the third child exits, which is 3 seconds after the program started.

The second program calls `wait()` inside the loop that creates the children. So it doesn't start child 2 until after child 1 has exited. So the total time is the sum of all the sleep times, rather than just the largest time.

It's much easier to see the difference when you indent the code properly.

Comment: I don't understand how the 3 children are started at the same time. I thought that in order to repeat fork() we have to finish the iteration of the current --for-- wich mean --sleep--.and --exit--.

Comment: There are two processes, the parent and the child. Only the child executes `sleep(i)`. The parent continues looping.

Answer (score 2):

So, here is some things to understand first:

Fork:

- creates a new process that copies all data from the current process (like a brain transplant).

  - The child process gets 0 as a value from the fork the parent gets the ID of the child process
- This new process then runs concurrently with the other processes.

  - This means that it won't wait for other processes to finish unless told otherwise.

Wait(NULL):

- Waits for a child process (of this process) to finish executing
- If there are no remainig child processes (of this process), then it returns automatically.

So for the first problem:

The max sleep time is 3 seconds (i= 3).
Since the processes don't wait on each other (except for when they are about to terminate), the whole process only takes 3 seconds (the sleeps happen concurrently).

Try understanding the second on your own, feel free to ask questions.